# Trying to find a short story (Town defending from invaders using tunnels)

Tags: story-identification

#### Main plot

A long while ago, I read a story that had a small group of villagers defending their town/planet against an invading force. When the troops showed up, they all just disappeared.

They had tunnels all through the town and were able to set up a guerrilla resistance and slowly overwhelm the troops until they holed up in a forest camp and were destroyed.

It was definitely sci-fi, but didn't use a whole ton of theming. It took place on a small planet (farming colony maybe?). The troops came in on dropships from space. Unfortunately I can't remember a lot more.

Anyone know what it may have been called / who wrote it?

#### Other info

I read it probably 5-10 years ago, though I don't know the age of the story itself. And it was a short story, not a novel.

#### EDIT:

Just remembered something else... the story opens (and closes) with an older gentleman on a hill overlooking the town casually cleaning his laser(?) rifle and then making his way off-scene with a hovercraft. (I remember both he and the other townspeople not actually being that concerned, just kind of dealing with it as though it was a storm or something.)

Comment: What was science fiction or fantasy about this story?

Comment: It was definitely sci-fi, but didn't use a whole ton of theming. It took place on a small planet (farming colony maybe?). The troops came in on dropships from space. Unfortunately I can't remember a lot more. :/

Comment: I know this short story, read it plenty. The humans who had crash landed generations ago had managed to survive invaders/raids by tunneling into underground warrens. When humanity came to rescue them, the natives could not distinguish between the previous raiders and the rescuers. I think one of the rescuers gets killed by being dragged into the hole and stabbed to death. In the end the rescuers give up, realizing there was no way to realistically go down into the tunnel network and rescue folks. It's a Silver Age story, Piper or Harrison I think, but trying my best to find in my collection.